# Where do my own classes go in CodeIgniter 2.1.2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, entity, entities

I have some problems to use my own classes using codeigniter. If it is not an error, it always says that the class can not be loaded.
For example, I created a class "Student" with atributes and only getter and setter methods, so I need to use that class in a model to return an array of "Students"(what I can not do with "load->library") or to receive a "Student"  for storing it, and I also need that class for my controller to do something with "Student"

I am working in Windows and I don't want to use an ORM because de app is not big.

I also want to do something like this in my model:

```
while(something){
    $arr[] = new Student();
}
return $arr;
```

What can I do? I will be grateful for your answers.

(PD: I'm sorry, I am not an English speaker)

**I solved it**
The only thing I had to do was create the file Student.php (where the class Student is) and put it on Libraries, after that:

```
$this->upload->library("Student.php");
```

and after that we can "instanciar" the class .

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and select it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What operating system are you developing on?

On Unix based operating systems the file system is case sensitive so make sure that when your calling the library for example as:

`$this->load->library('student');` that the file on the disk is called `Student.php`. On Windows however the file system is case insensitive so this is not really an issue.

For more information you should read:

[Case sensitive file names in Linux and not in Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/339068/Case-sensitive-file-names-in-Linux-and-not-in-Wind)

**UPDATE**

From your comments it should like you wish to use your class like a library in which case you should include the file in the 'libraries' directory and load the library which is outlined in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/libraries.html).

```
$this->load->library('students');
```

THen your will be able to use your method as such

```
$this->students->method_name();
```

Make sure you load the library manually as mentioned above [autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html).

Comment: I am working on Windows, but where do I have to put "Students.php"?
Because I want to do something like this:
while(something){
 $arr[] = new Student();
}
return arr;

Comment: What is 'Students' Does it hold business logic? e.g. is it a model -   http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: No, only getters and setters. But I want to use it in my models and controllers

Comment: Yes, I did it before, but in that case I can not do an array of Students

Comment: Would you be able to post the contents of your students.php file so that I can see what it contains to try and diagnose your problem? try uploading to pastebin

Comment: Thanks, I just put it on libraries